# AngularJS load ng-repeat into another ng-repeat with ajax call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, http, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm new to angular and would like some help in solving the following issue. This is the code I currently have, simply getting an array of results from the server using a post request and displaying them using the ng-repeat directive:

```
<div id="mainW" ng-controller="MediaController">

    <div id="mediaBodyW" ng-repeat="media in medias">
        <div class="mediaW" data-id="{{media.id}}">
        <div class="mediaNum">{{media.num}}</div>
        <div class="mediaN">{{media.name}}</div>

        <div id="loadSubs" ng-click="loadSubMedias(media.id)">load sub medias</div>
        <div id="subMediaW"></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

This is my controller:

```
app.controller("MediaController",['$scope','$http','$httpParamSerializerJQLike',function($scope,$http,$httpParamSerializerJQLike){

    $scope.medias = [];

    try {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'media.php',
            data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike({"request":"getAllMedia"}),
            headers: {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).then(function (ans) {
            $scope.medias = ans.data;
        }, function (error) {
            console.error(JSON.stringify(error));
        });
    }
    catch (ex) {
        console.error("Error: " + ex.toString());
    }
}]);
```

Now, what I would like to achieve, is: on clicking the div with id of "loadSubs", run another $http post query which will load an array of results into the "subMediaW". Of course the query and appending of html should be unique for each media element, and each time a data is loaded for a particular element all previous results should be cleared, all this while taking into account that the loaded data will be also manipulated in the future.

Can someone please help me understand how can I do this using AngularJS?

Comment: where do you want to append new datas? I couldnt see where you want to second ng-repeat...

Comment: Inside the div:  <div id="subMediaW"></div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you should have a function in your controller with the name **loadSubMedias** and instead of simply taking media.id you can send whole media object to it (later on we will add new data into this object as an another property).

```
$scope.loadSubMedias = function (media) {
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'media.php',
        data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike({"mediaId":media.id}),
        headers: {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).then(function (response) {
        // now add subDatas into main data Object
        media.subMedias = response.data;
    });
}
```

and in your controller just use ng-repeat like this

```
<div id="mainW" ng-controller="MediaController">

    <div id="mediaBodyW" ng-repeat="media in medias">
        <div class="mediaW" data-id="{{media.id}}">
        <div class="mediaNum">{{media.num}}</div>
        <div class="mediaN">{{media.name}}</div>

        <div id="loadSubs" ng-click="loadSubMedias(media)">load sub medias</div>
        <div id="subMediaW" ng-repeat="subMedia in media.subMedias">
             <pre>{{subMedia | json}}</pre>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
$scope.prevMedia = null; //use this to store last clicked media object

$scope.loadSubMedias = function(media){
  $http.post().... //make api call for subMedia here
  .then(function(res){
      media.subMediaW = res.data // attach a subMediaW array to the media object
      media.showSubMedia = true; // set variable true to make submedia visible for current media object, this will be used with ng-if attribute in html
      if($scope.prevMedia != null) $scope.prevMedia.showSubMedia = false; // if last selected media object is not null, hide its submedia
   })
}
```

and html

```
<div id="mainW" ng-controller="MediaController">

  <div id="mediaBodyW" ng-repeat="media in medias">
    <div class="mediaW" data-id="{{media.id}}">
    <div class="mediaNum">{{media.num}}</div>
    <div class="mediaN">{{media.name}}</div>

    <div id="loadSubs" ng-click="loadSubMedias(media)">load sub medias</div>
    <div id="subMediaW" ng-repeat="submedia in media.subMediaW" ng-if="media.showSubMedia"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```